# Process finished with exit code 138 (interrupted by signal 10: SIGBUS)

Tags: python, macos, pycharm

I am using PyCharm 2021.1 on MacOS and when I import keyboard library my program crashes without exception, I just get "Process finished with exit code 138 (interrupted by signal 10: SIGBUS) " error in my console.

```
import keyboard
```

Is there a way to fix this in PyCharm?

Comment: If you use [keyboard](https://pypi.org/project/keyboard/) it claims that MacOS support is experimental. Probably it is worth creating an issue in the projects' Github repo.